# In mosquitto can I allow publishing only for some IPs but subscribe anywhere?

Tags: mosquitto

In mosquitto can I allow only some IPs to publish, but allow to subscribe from
anywhere ?

I want to make mosquitto only allow publishing from some IPs for security reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mosquitto provides security through username and password authentication as well as limiting access to topics with access control lists. There are details in the mosquitto.conf man page: http://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html

There is also a plugin for database backends that might contain security usernames/passwords https://github.com/jpmens/mosquitto-auth-plug